# Changing the leading and trailing margins for a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Is there a way to change the leading and trailing margins for a UINavigationBar controlled by a UINavigationController? I'm using a custom interface and it will help to leave more space on the left and right sides for the back and done buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the navigation frame on your navigation controller

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let space = 30
    self.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(space), y: 0, width: self.navigationBar.frame.size.width-CGFloat(space*2), height: self.navigationBar.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a myriad off questions around this on stackoverflow. On iOS <11, adding a negative spacer button works.

On iOS 11, swizzling `[_UINavigationBarContentView directionalLayoutMargins]` to return a zero value removes any trailing padding around the left/right items:

```
NSDirectionalEdgeInsets zeroMargins(id self, SEL _cmd) {
  return NSDirectionalEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

- (void) doIt {
    Class cl = objc_getClass("_UINavigationBarContentView");
    if (cl != nil) {
        method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod(cl, @selector(directionalLayoutMargins)), (IMP)zeroMargins);
    }
}
```